# C# Read file info from URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, url

In my ASP.NET MVC application I'm reading an external file from URL and saving it into a directory on my server. I do this in a loop for every few seconds to have actual data if the file was modified.

What I need is to recognize that the `LastWrittenTime` of the file accessed via the URL is different from file already downloaded to the server. I cannot use `FileInfo` class because "URI formats are not supported".

So how do I get the last written time of the file from the URL without needing to download the full file for every loop?

Comment: are you reading the url from a file or browser address bar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming your HTTP Server allows this.

```
System.Net.WebRequest req = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create("http:\\your\url.ext");
req.Method = "HEAD";
using (System.Net.WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse())
{
    DateTime LastModified;
    if(DateTime.TryParse(resp.Headers.Get("Last-Modified"), out LastModified))
    { 
        //Check if date is good and then go to full download method.
    }
}
```

When this method doesn't work because the server doesn't allow it. Then the only way of doing this is by fully downloading the file.

Comment: Also if you need other information, this wiki page shows a list of possible values the head may contain.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you can't.

When it's a webpage you want to download, you might hope that the server would set the `LastModified` attribute of a `WebResponse` correctly to get the date the page was last modified. But even this is not something you can always rely on.

When it's a file, there's no way to tell the date unless you saved the file on your own disk. (Like you are doing now.) And even then, depending on server settings, you might be getting the date the file was created on your disc, not on the server you're downloading from.

Comment: Depends on the file, and where it's created, assuming he's creating it on the server (since he's downloading it every so much seconds). Then the last modified date would be set by the server.